# Approach to use for animating a 2D game like Tower Defence on iOS/android

Tags: java, android, ios, animation, graphics

If I am going to make a game like Tower Defence on iOS or Android, do I need to use OpenGL ES extensively? Or am I merely using textures without using other features like geometry transformation, lightning, drawing primitive shape and such?
Secondly, if I am only using the sprite-sheet to animate the game, could I stick to the native platform provided library without the use of OpenGL ES? For example on iOS, using the UIImageView class animation method to perform an animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is such a complex question that you will hardly receive a conclusive answer.

In short: There is no need to touch OpenGL at all to do a game.

Every method that you describe would work, but with various advantages and disadvantages. A short excurse for inbuilt frameworks on Android:

1. Use standard views (like FrameLayouts): The Framework can do most of your work (animation, z-sorting, ...) but you will run frequently into weird layout errors and surprising performance hits. This is because you are essentially perusing a UI framework for a game. However, for a very simple game it might be just the right thing to do.
2. Use Canvas painting: Android contains a good and rather fast 2D graphics library in that. You can use it for games, it will deliver enough performance for many games. However, you have to do more yourself already (e.g., z-sorting, animation) and some high-end effects are still not possible
3. OpenGL ES: Best performance, most choices. Good luck, when starting from scratch, there is **A LOT** to do before you get even the simplest stuff on the screen. On the other hand, you can do things that are almost impossible with the other approaches. Also, it's possible to reuse parts of the code for multiple platforms.
4. Renderscript: In my experience even worse than working directly with OpenGL in that the learning curve is even steeper.

In short, design the game first, then decide on which framework provides enough functionality for that without being too complex.

And finally: Think about *not* doing all the plumbing yourself but take a look at the existing game engines ([Unity](http://unity3d.com/) for example). Almost anything you ever need will be in there; furthermore, some of these engines work even cross-plattform: Write your game once, publish it on iOS **AND** Android!